# Unexpected result in my query with inclusion of "to" as a route in row 1

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

what can be the error in this query? When I run it "to" becomes a route in row 1, then the main result starts from row 2.

```
SELECT 
usertype,
CONCAT (start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) AS route,
COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS INT64)/60),2) AS Duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY 
start_station_name, end_station_name,usertype
ORDER BY
num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

i as expecting the main result to begin from row 1.

Comment: maybe row 2 has a higher num_trips the row 1, but with oout data, this can only be a speculation

Comment: What do you mean by “the main result starts from row 2”? A query gives a result so there’s no such thing as a “main” result, just a result. Do you mean that the route column has a value of “to”? If so, then you obviously have null values in the start/end columns

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try once by putting single quote to start_station_name and end_station_name .

Example:
SELECT CONCAT('T.P.', ' ', 'Bar') as author;

Output:
author
T.P. Bar